# How to remove parent XML node from command line

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I would like to know which would be the best way to delete only the Vegetables Product Node without affecting the Meat Product Node.

```
<Product>
    <Type>Meat</Type>
    <Object>
      <ID>1</ID>
    </Object>
  </Product>
<Product>
    <Type>Vegetables</Type>
    <Object>
      <ID>1</ID>
    </Object>
  </Product>
```

Comment: The sample snippet is no complete XML file. Can we assume you mean an xml file with a root tag wrapped around?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your snippet in a top level tag to create a well-formed XML file. Then use e.g. the command line tool [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to modify the XML.

For your case the staep by step instructions:

1. Add a toplevel tag, say, `MyTopLevelTag`, so that your XML files looks like :

   Meat
           
             1
           
         
       
           Vegetables
           
             1

Save it as `how-to-remove-vegetables_wrapped.xml`

1. Install [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). (Under OSX you can use [homebrew](http://brew.sh)).
2. Type in your shell:

   xml ed -d "/MyTopLevelTag/Product[Type = 'Vegetables']" how-to-remove-vegetables_wrapped.xml

The magic is in  the XPath `/MyTopLevelTag/Product[Type = 'Vegetables']`: You select the `Product` tag, but you restrict it to its children with the `type` value of `'Vegetables'`.